# How can one prevent thief of academic work and get recognition/listed as a co-author?

Tags: publications

There was a problem in my first lab (I suspect but do not know for sure) that my first PI gave some of the results of my project’s work I found for her to another student to present at a small school/institution based conference; it could also be the case that this other student or his buddy who also works in this lab and has access stole it without her knowledge as well.  I’m not sure why she (or they) did this to me as I was never rude to anybody.  I also had to fund this botany project she wanted me to work on and buy supplies for it too out of my own pocket even though it was not a project of my own choosing (it didn’t amount to much but this isn’t the point).  Anyway, I decided to just ‘let it go’ (i.e. not report it or make a big deal out of it) as I’ve had enough hardship and drama in my life – I’m an older/non-traditional student who just wants to move forward.  I decided to just move on to another lab and PI.

Now I’m in another lab, and the professor reminds me from time to time that he own my lab notebook and research.  Luckily, the project is funded by NIH, so I haven’t had to buy any supplies yet.  I’ve already decided that I’m not going to spend anymore money out of pocket, so if I’m asked to this time, I will report it to the Dean, the Media, and whoever else will listen and walk away…  Anyway, I understand that my new PI and/or the school will benefit financially from any discoveries which I’m cool with as I’m in this for the mental stimulation and because it’s a stepping stone, but does this mean that I have no intellectual rights to the work I’m doing?  Here’s a very clear “yes/no” question that I’d like to have answered: **Will my name be listed as a co-author on any papers published as a result of the project assuming I continue doing a good job?**

I’m also having some issues changing my official focus (i.e. switching from a professional/terminal biotech master’s to pure biology masters with a more rigorous science focus and the option to pursue a PhD later).  I initiated this process 3 months ago when I was accepted into the new lab.  At that time, I was told by my new advisor/new PI that I wouldn’t need to reapply or resubmit transcripts, but the problem hasn’t been fixed yet, and my new advisor/PI hasn’t responded to questions related to this issue thus far.  **What should my next steps be?**

I want this masters degree to work out.  I’m not a ‘trouble maker type’ and never have been.  In fact, I frequently get taken advantage of, have my ideas and work stolen, etc.  I previously posted a longer more detailed version of this post with more background, and others criticized that post for being too long/too specific to my situation/whiny.  I’m a 39 year old who’s seen life and death up close, worked in a variety of jobs, and had my fair share of hard knocks – not a whiner but I’ve also been around the block enough to know BS when I see it.  I’m asking you what I can do about it and how to ensure I’m not taken advantage of yet again.  I want to earn my master’s, but if I’m going to have a repeat of my work being stolen, maybe I’m at the wrong school or maybe I shouldn’t bother at all…  **How can a student ensure that he/she is given the credit/recognition that is due?**

Comment: I'm the one that down voted your question... Please limit your question to one topic. You asked multiple questions that may be pretty much related together, which are really hard to answer... By the way, I think your questions might be more appropriate for someone in your university such as graduate school coordinator or something like that, who is more familiar with your situation or at least you can describe it more freely to him/her. I can understand you are really frustrated and I'm sorry for that but it's really hard for us to tell what to do or not to do in your life...

Comment: This question is still very very long, and has lots of unnecessary content such as a discussion of your previous question. Your "hard knocks" are completely irrelevant: you don't get academic credit for seeing life and death or working a variety of jobs, you get academic credit for doing academic work.

Comment: I understand you're emotionally involved and feeling the need to air this out, but a Q&A forum isn't the appropriate channel. Please rewrite making it shorter and more neutral, with *one* specific question per post.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has many different layers, some of which we can't answer as they are specific to individuals.

But this we can:

- Legally, your discoveries belong to the university. If they lead to any kind of monetary reward, such as if they are commercialized via a patent or a company that markets a product, then every university has a policy that specifies who gets to share in the reward. The inventor is generally one of those who get to share. (I'll add this: Few people have gotten rich this way. Most inventions and scientific discoveries get you scientific credit but not any kind of money.)
- Professional ethics dictates that if you significantly participated in the intellectual developments presented in a paper, then you should be a co-author of it. *Will* you actually be a co-author? We don't know -- it depends on whether everyone else on the paper behaves ethically. But at least you know that you *should* be  co-author. (And here, I'll add this: All of the stories on this forum notwithstanding, the vast majority of scientists behave ethically and *will* make sure that everyone who significantly participated in the intellectual development shown in a paper is, in fact, a co-author.) Of course, that also comes with responsibilities, such as participating in the writing and editing.

Comment: Right. What _should_ happen and what _may_ happen are not necessarily the same. It is important to be "on the same page" with your advisor(s), so that you know what _their_ appraisal of the/your situation is, and so that you can work to reconcile their perspective with your own. If you truly ascertain that people are unethical and dishonest, it is a serious problem... and there is generally no easy fix. On the other hand, it is entirely possible that there are "simply" misunderstandings, that _could_ be overcome. Talk to your advisor(s), preferably in person (so you can gauge body language).

Comment: Yes, precisely. *Communicate* with the people you work with.